Check cell type using xlsx package
I have an excel file like this:

I use xlsx to parse a sheet's data to json:
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

const wb = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
const ws = wb.Sheets['Sheet'];
const json = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);

The json object is just a key/value objects:
[
    {
      account_number: '109325380759',
      amount: 1000000,
      channel_code: 'VN_VCB',
      account_name: 'DANICA MARIE REYES',
      __rowNum__: 1
    },
    {
      account_number: 4300540341,
      amount: 1000000,
      channel_code: 'VN_VCB',
      account_name: 'JONEL PINPIN',
      __rowNum__: 2
    },
    {
      account_number: 9366892320,
      amount: 1000000,
      channel_code: 'VN_VCB',
      account_name: 'ALBERT GADIANA',
      __rowNum__: 3
    }
  ]

My goal is to find a way to get the cell's type (number, text...) of all cells except the header cells. Any solution for this?

You need to loop cells in worksheet object as described in Common Spreadsheet Format (CSF), and then get the cell object, and read type in t property as described in Cell Object

t     | type: b Boolean, e Error, n Number, d Date, s Text, z Stub

To skip header, you can start reading from next row index depending on your header row
Steps:

get cells range
get cell address object (column and row as 0-index number)
get cell address (string address)
get cell object
read type from t property
to skip header: start reading from N-th/your header row

demo:
const range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(ws['!ref']);

const types = {
  b: 'Boolean',
  e: 'Error',
  n: 'Number',
  d: 'Date',
  s: 'Text',
  z: 'Stub'
}

for (let R = range.s.r; R <= range.e.r; ++R) {

  for (let C = range.s.c; C <= range.e.c; ++C) {

   // to skip header: start from N-th/header row
   // if(R>1) {

    const cellAddressObj = {c: C, r: R };

    const cellAddress = XLSX.utils.encode_cell(cellAddressObj);

    const cellVal = ws[cellAddress];

    const type = types[cellVal.t];

    console.log('address: ', cellAddress, '\naddress col:row: ', cellAddressObj, '\ntype: ', type);
  }
  //}
}

